# The family $\{(U_{\alpha}\times V_{\beta})\}$ covers the product $M\times N$.

Tags: differential-geometry, elementary-set-theory

I was trying to show that if $M^{n}$ is differentiable manifold with differential structure $\{(U_{\alpha},\varphi_{\alpha})\}$ and $N^{m}$ is a differentiable manifold with differential structure $\{(V_{\beta},\psi_{\beta})\}$ then the family $\{(U_{\alpha}\times V_{\beta},\varphi_{\alpha}\times\psi_{\beta})\}$ is a differential structure on $M^n\times N^{m}$. But my doubt arises when I am obtaining the union
$$\bigcup_{\alpha,\beta}U_{\alpha}\times V_{\beta}$$

I my opinion, this should be the same as

$$\left(\bigcup_{\alpha}U_{\alpha}\right)\times\left(\bigcup_{\beta}V_{\beta}\right)$$

Then, I want to clarify is whether this property holds when we are manipulating double indexed unions with products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set
$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in A, \beta\in B} U_\alpha\times V_\beta$$
consists of pairs $(u,v)$ such that there are $\alpha\in A$ and $\beta\in B$ for which $u\in U_\alpha$ and $v\in V_\beta$.

On the other hand, the set
$$\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha\right)\times \left(\bigcup_{\beta\in B}V_\beta\right)$$
consists of pairs $(u,v)$ such that $u\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} U_\alpha$ and $v\in \bigcup_{\beta\in B}V_\beta$, that is, the set of pairs such that there is an $\alpha\in A$ for which $u\in U_\alpha$ and a $\beta\in B$ for which $v\in V_\beta$.

So they are indeed the same set.

---

Of course, if both families $U_\alpha$ and $V_\alpha$ were indexed by the same indices $\alpha\in A$, then there is a difference: taking the product before the union, i.e.
$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} U_\alpha\times V_\alpha$$ would result in only pairs $(u,v)$ where $u\in U_\alpha$ and $v\in V_\alpha$ for the same $\alpha$, while taking the union before the product, i.e.
$$\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha\right)\times \left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}V_\alpha\right)$$
would result in pairs $(u,v)$ with $u\in U_\alpha$ and $v\in V_{\alpha'}$ for any (possibly different) $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true.

In general, we have $A\times\bigcup_iB_i=\bigcup_i(A\times B_i)$ for any sets $A$ and $B_i$. 
Apply it twice.